# Python OpenCV TypeError : "corners is not a numpy array, neither a scalar"

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

Running OpenCV findChessboardCorners, I get this error:

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(_Image, size, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
TypeError: corners is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

This is my relevant code:

```
size = (10,6)
_Image = cv2.imread(filePath, 0)
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(_Image, size, cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should do this:

```
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(_Image, size, flags=cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH+cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK+cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE)
```

Based on the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#cv2.findChessboardCorners), the third parameter is `corners` and looks like you were expecting it to be `flags`.